# requirejs unable to find module returning undefined

Tags: requirejs

i've been working with require before, but never ran into this issue,
maybe i got a path wrong somewhere but this is my filestructure:

```
js
├───main.js
│
├───app
│   ├───app.js
│   ├───hello.js
│   ├───world.js
│   │
│   └───models
│       └───game.js
│
└───vendor
    ├───jquery.js
    └───require.js
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery':   '../js/vendor/jquery'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});

require(['app/app', 'jquery', 'app/models/game'], function (App, $, Game) {
    console.log(arguments);
    $(function () {
        console.log('why is my App undefined?', App);
        App.init();

    });
});
```

app/app.js

```
define('App', ['hello', 'world'], function (hello, world) {

    var App = {};

    App.init = function () {
        alert(hello + ' ' + world);
    };

    return App;
});
```

the code fires alright, however my dependencies seem to fail on app or hello or world module, App logs as undefined, so does my game module.

app/app should be the right path to my App module or am I thinking that wrong?

**Update**

I thought the capital A for App fixed the issue (but at the same time I took a swing at Jlange's comment, so I fired up the `app/App` module from the `index.html`. Which seemed ok, but after continuing the development it came up again.

I can load every module in the same directory just fine, but I cannot modules from subdirectories.

like the initial example couldn't load app/App from within the Main module, so can the app/App module not import the models/Game module.

I literally have no clue what this can be, as I said before, I have worked with requirejs and have not run into this issue.

**Update 2**
I can make it work if I drop all the named modules,

```
define([dependencies], function (dependencies) {});
```

that works fine
but as soon as I change it into a named module I cannot find it

```
define("moduleA", ['subdir/moduleB'], function (moduleB) {
    console.log(moduleB); // >> undefined
});
define("subdir/moduleB", [dependencies], function (dependencies) { return 'B'; });
```

Comment: Why do you include jquery in your require statement? I usually define it in the application file like `define(['jquery',], function($)`

Comment: well I have it in my main because the main has general require config, and boots the App, that's why it has jquery included there to boot the app on document ready state.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I was really interested in seeing the solution, as I use require.js a lot.

Comment: well, it really strikes me as odd that they discourage you to name modules, I thought it would be a natural way to create your own namespacing without having it related to your prefered folder structure. but I got it wrong :) took me only a few hours to figure out, so I'm quite relieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited**

after many tries, to fix the above code, and reading up in the requirejs help pages, I found a small passage, saying it is best not to use named modules and let the optimizer name them for you.

So I decided to remove all module names

moduleA.js

```
define(['subdir/moduleB'], function (moduleB) {
    console.log(moduleB); // >> 'B'
});
```

subdir/moduleB.js

```
define([dependencies], function (dependencies) { return 'B'; });
```

this works just fine...
don't know how I got fixed on using those moduleNames, Thought it would be better to name your modules.

Comment: it can be useful in development until your files and directory structure stabilises.

Comment: true but don't you then have to go over your entire list of modules to remove them? seems kind of overkill in medium to big applications. I'm looking into mantriJs too, just cus i'm curious... not really planning any development in it yet. though it uses namespaces instead of file paths.

Comment: hopefully by the time you code base starts to get to that sort of size your directory structure will have stabilised enough not to warrant it.